# In Excel how do insert a copy of a "parent" cell to the right of each of its "children."

Tags: excel

I'm stuggling to express it in words but this is the effect I am looking for.

CHECK THIS OUT:

[image]

I need each item to have its "parent" value as the cell to its right, but this is complicated by the massively inconsistent number of children each parent has.

Thank you for reading and I hope I can learn how to solve this.

Comment: Is VBA an option? You could achieve the desired result using a VBA quite easily...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple `if()` formula will help here.

Stick the following in H4 (your first child) and copy down

```
=IF(LEFT(F3, 4)="PARE", F3, IF(LEFT(F4, 4)="PARE", "", H3))
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: A simple and elegant solution, thank you very much you are a star.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, this would work:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column F

For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop from row 1 to last
    If Not IsNumeric(ws.Cells(i, 6).Value) Then 'check if value is numeric in column 6 = Column F
        ParentValue = ws.Cells(i, 6) 'if is not a number then it is a parent
    Else
        ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = ParentValue 'add parent on column 8 = column H
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```